# React Popup not showing correctly

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, async-await, react-hooks

0

I am having some issue using `useState` in React. I have a customized component `Dialog` which can pass down `renderAction` and `renderContent` as props.

So I managed to open the first dialog and everything seems in order, which is the `<Dialog>` tag in the bottom of code. but after I got response back from server, I want to show the second `Dialog` popup and close the first `Dialog` popup. but after the first one disappear second one never pop up.

the server call is made successfully, so `response.success` is true, that is why `setPopupOpen=false` (close the first popup) works, but I don't know why since I have set the `secondPopupOpen=true`, but why the same method will not work to show the second dialog popup.

AppNav.js

```
const AppNav = () => {
    //...
    const [popupOpen, setPopupOpen] = useState(false);
    const [secondPopupOpen, setSecondPopupOpen] = useState(false);
    const [input, setInput] = useState('');

const renderContent = () => { 
  return ( 
    <form>
     <input
      type="text"
      onChange={e => setInput(e.target.value)}
      value={input}
      onBlur={() =>delay(() =>setInput(''),150}
      placeholder='placeholder here...'
     />
    </form>
  );
};

const renderAction = () => { 
  const handleSubmit = async() => {
    //some server calls here
    // response is what got back from server call
  try{
    if(response.success){
      setPopupOpen(false);
      setSecondPopupOpen(true);
      return (
       <
        <Dialog
         open={secondPopupOpen}
         renderContent={() => <span>Message:</span>}
         renderAction={() => <span>operation successful!</span>}
     />
    )
   }
  }
  return ( 
    <Button onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit</Button>
  );
};
  return (
   <Dialog
     open={popupOpen}
     renderContent={RenderContent}
     renderAction={RenderAction}
   />
  )
}
```

Comment: can you please provide sandbox link or full code for this component ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two `Dialog` components. The reason why your `Dialog` inside the `handleSubmit` is not working is that it is not being returned to the functional component, only to the `handleSubmit` function.

One way that you can do this is by saving the `renderContent` and `renderAction` on the state and pass it to the `Dialog` being returned in your component (at the end of the file).

However, you don't want to store JSX in the state. Try to save only the text that you want to show in the state, like `Message` instead of `<span>{Message}</span>`

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the return statement from handle submit and add the second dialog below the first dialog as below.

```
return (
  <>
   <Dialog
     open={popupOpen}
     renderContent={RenderContent}
     renderAction={RenderAction}
   />
   <Dialog
     open={secondPopupOpen}
     renderContent={() => <span>Message:</span>}
     renderAction={() => <span>operation successful!</span>}
     />
  </>
)
```

Previously your second dialog is not showing up, there are two possible reasons.
The first one is it might because you are returning it to the renderAction of the first dialog, and first dialog is closed at that point in time.
The second one is setState is `asynchronous` so it might possible that it gets return before setting secondPopupOpen to true.

Comment: thanks for the help but seems its still not working :( where do you think I need to place the `setSecondPopupOpen`?

Comment: You are setting setSecondPopupOpen correctly, you just need to remove the return statement inside handle submit.  Could you just tell where does that Dialog comes from, which means which package/library you are using for it?